# Returning custom sets in scala as an extension of function

Tags: scala, set

I'm trying to write a function that returns a set of integers, when I specify it to as a parameter.
I know that in scala, the trait `Set[A]` extends `(A => Boolean)`, so I tried something like the below:

```scala
def foo(x: Int): Set[Int] = {
    return {(y: Int) => y match
        case x => true
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

But doesn't work, returning

```
 found   : A => Boolean
 required: Set[A]
```

Since it isn't in the form it wants, I assume. How can I change my code so it returns a valid set?

Answer (score 2):

`Set[A]` is a subtype of `A => Boolean`, not the other way around

```
implicitly[Set[Int] <:< (Int => Boolean)]   // OK
implicitly[(Int => Boolean) <:< Set[Int]]   // ERROR
```

so the following is valid

```
val s: Int => Boolean = Set(1,2,3)
s(4)
// res0: Boolean = false
```

but not

```
val s: Set[Int] = (x: Int) => true   // Error: type mismatch
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand why this is the case, but how would you return Set types from functions?

Comment: @M80 _"return Set types from functions"_ what do you mean?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez What I mean is for the return type of my function foo() to be Set[Int], to essentially return a set, with the `elem` contained inside of it.

Comment: @M80 You could just do `def foo(x: Int): Set[Int] = Set(x)` but why not then just use set factory directly?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `Set[A]` is a function `A => Boolean`, true. But it is also a collection that can be traversed, filtered, mapped, etc. You can create something as a function and let the compiler turn it into an object... but only when the type you are implementing that way is **single abstract method**.

Meanwhile, `Set[A]` in Scala 2.13 has, well, [quite a lot of methods](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/717fa7c4cf6af250d378c569dc2ab928f66de20f/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala) to implement.

```
    def size: Int
    def isEmpty: boolean
    def knownSize: Int
    def filter(pred: A => Boolean): Set[A]
    def filterNot(pred: A => Boolean): Set[AnyA
    def removedAll(that: IterableOnce[A]): Set[A]
    def diff(that: collection.Set[A]): Set[A]
    def subsetOf(that: collection.Set[A]): Boolean
    def intersect(that: collection.Set[A]): Set[A]
    def view: View[A]
    def contains(elem: A): Boolean
    def incl(elem: A): Set[A]
    def excl(elem: A): Set[A]
    def iterator: Iterator[A]
    def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit
```

and how would you create that `Set[Int]`... would you iterate over all possible `Int`s? You could make that lazily, but the moment someone called `iterator`, `foreach`, etc you would have to materialize these values.

For that reason it is rather unlikely that you will ever use full implementation of `Set[Int]` materialized from a function `Int => Boolean`. At best you could implement your own `Set` implementation that provides only some fraction of the `Set` interface that doesn't require iterating over whole `Int` type.

The opposite is trivial though. `set.apply(int)` is what you are able to do because `Set[Int]` extends `Int => Boolean`, so you can assign `Set[Int]` as a `Int => Boolean` function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return a set instance? like this:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_222).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def set(x: Int): Set[Int] = Set(x)
set: (x: Int)Set[Int]

scala> val s = set(1)
s: Set[Int] = Set(1)

scala> s(1)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> s(2)
res1: Boolean = false
```